# java update screen in thread

Tags: java, android

Im writing a script which consists of a thread with a wait. If the thread get executed, it doesn't update the screen. In the script i change a picture to another picture, but it doesn't show it until I press the button again. So the main question is: After setting an different Image Resource, i need to update the screen.

Here is the code:

```
 public void Start(View view) {

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i =0;
            while(i<12) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    try {

                        Setfoto(i);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Begonnen met loop");
                        Log.i(TAG, "i = " + i);
                        i = i +1;
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                }

            }
        }
    };

    Thread buckysThread = new Thread(r);
    buckysThread.start();

}

public void Setfoto(int nummer) {
    if (nummer == 1) {
        een.setImageResource(R.drawable.eerster);
        Log.i(TAG, "Foto 1 wordt rood");

    } if(nummer ==2) {
        twee.setImageResource(R.drawable.eerster);
        Log.i(TAG, "Foto 2 wordt rood");
    } if(nummer ==3) {
        drie.setImageResource(R.drawable.tweer);
        Log.i(TAG, "Foto 3 wordt rood");
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't update the UI from a background thread. Read some Android documentation about how to update the UI and you will figure it out on your own. If not, at least you will be able to improve your question and not make these mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have some sort of way to run code on the UI thread, which is responsible for updating the contents of the screen and manipulating views.

`Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)` can be called. Any code placed in there will be run on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `runOnUiThread`, `AsyncTask` or `Thread-Handler` to implement your task

1. `Activity.runOnUiThread`

   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
               //Do something on UiThread
           }
       });
2. Thread-Handler

[Communicating with the UI Thread](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)

3. AsyncTask

[AsyncTask Tutorial](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/)